# Has the prophecy in Deuteronomy 28:68 been fulfilled?

Tags: deuteronomy

Deuteronomy 28:68
The LORD will send you back in ships to Egypt on a journey I said you should never make again. There you will offer yourselves for sale to your enemies as male and female slaves, but no one will buy you.

The LORD seems to be going back to his promise. Maybe it will never be fulfilled. Maybe it is just a threat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book of Deuteronomy has the following structure of Moses' final four orations, collectively constitute a restatement of the israelite covenant first pronounced in Ex 19-23.

1. First Oration: Deut 1:6 – 4:43.  Historical background
2. Second Oration:  Deut 4:44 – 26:19.  The Law of the Ten Commandments expanded
3. Third Oration:  Deut 27:1 – 28:68.  Blessings and Curses of the covenant
4. Fourth Oration:  Deut 29:1 – 30:20.  Renewal of the Covenant

The third oration consists of a series of blessings for keeping the covenant and a series of curses for not keeping the covenant.

The curses are not "threats" but simple statements of fact of what would happen if Israel abandoned God.  They are equivalent to saying something like, "If people do not keep the law of the land, anarchy will erupt!"  That is not a threat, it is a simple statement of sociological fact.  Thus, they are not specific prophecies.

Comment: Verse 58 warns the people that if they do not carefully follow all the words of the law given to them by God, and if they do not revere the glorious and awesome name of the Lord their God, then their disobedience would be punished.

Comment: @Lesley - quite correct - the blessings were essentially a promise of God's protection.  Without that protection (as occurred in the 6th century BC) they would be subject to invasion, "the sword", "famine", "wild beasts", "pestilence", etc.  That is what happened under Nebuchadnezzar.